# Where are Function and Function.prototype Objects in prototype chain?

Tags: javascript

I am reading about prototype chaining in JS. I came across this schematic online.

[image]

My question is:

Since function A and B are Object of type Function shouldn't there be a Function and a Function.prototype Object somewhere in the inheritance tree?

Comment: The functions are used to construct objects, they are not themselves in the objects' prototype chain. Functions have instead a `prototype` property which is added to the chain of objects they construct.

Comment: @Touffy Can you cite any source which mentions that Function and its prototype dont participate in prototype chaining? And if its true, how can we be able to use their properties?

Comment: `function B` doesn't inherit from `function A`.  `function B` is the constructor for an Object with the prototype of `B`.

Comment: @SKG The vocabulary is a bit confusing, so read carefully. If you want a source, [here you go](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-objects). Though metame's answer says it all.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor functions are not being diagrammed hierarchically in the prototype chain, the Objects they construct are the focus of the diagram.

There is an important distinction (and confusion) in the difference between `[[proto]]` (accessible via `obj.__proto__` where `obj` is any `Object`) and the `Prototype` property of an object, viz. `obj.prototype`.

This snippet may explain:

```js
function A(name){
  this.name = name
  this.getName = function(){ return name }
}

function B(name){
  A.call(this, name)
}

var b = new B('yep')
var anotherB = new B('me too')

console.log(b.getName()) // yep

/* both B & A constructors inherit from Function but B doesn't inherit from A */
console.log(B instanceof Function && A instanceof Function) //true
console.log(B.prototype === A.prototype) //false
console.log(B.__proto__ === A.__proto__) //true
console.log(B instanceof A) //false


/* an instance of B is not an instance of A */
console.log(b instanceof B) //true
console.log(b instanceof A) //false

/* an instance of B has the prototype of B but not the same [[proto]] as B */
console.log(B.prototype.isPrototypeOf(b)) //true
console.log(b.__proto__ === B.__proto__ ) //false

/* instances of B have the same [[proto]] but not the same [[proto]] as B */
console.log(b.__proto__ === anotherB.__proto__ ) //true
```

`function B` does not inherit from `function A`.  Both `function A` and `function B` inherit from `Function` which inherits from `Object`.  They both have identical Prototype chains (abbreviated).

`function A`: `function A` -> `Function` -> `Object`

`function B`: `function B` -> `Function` -> `Object`

Which is different from the Objects they construct.  In the case of the Object returned from `function B`, the prototype chain is `B` -> `A` -> `Object`.

Comment: I have edited the image to focus on what I want to use. Anyways. I have some problems with your answer.
1.function A -> Function -> Object.
Function A or B have their own prototype. Which are empty objects. How can they inherit from Function. Maybe I am missing something from your answer. Could you please elaborate a little?
2.Most importantly, please cite some source. Thanks.

Comment: When new objects are instantiated using a constructor function, the JS engine looks at the `prototype` property of the constructor function and uses that to set the prototype of the new object. You could simulate this without calling `new A()` by writing `var aInstance = Object.create(A.prototype)` (I mention this only for illustrative purposes). Note that the constructor function's own prototype is `Function.prototype` - same as for all other functions.

Comment: @MattBrowne Do you mean Function.prototype === B.prototype;? It returns false.

Comment: @SKG No, I mean `Object.getPrototypeOf(B) === Function.prototype`. The confusing part is that the internal prototype property (often referred to as `[[proto]]` in the literature and also accessible using `.__proto__` in most browsers) is not the same as the `prototype` property of constructor functions. The `prototype` property refers only to the prototype that will be used when that constructor creates new objects; it does not refer to the prototype of the constructor function itself.

Comment: A good reference is http://robotlolita.me/2011/10/09/understanding-javascript-oop.html. And for a deeper understanding of prototypes in general, refer to [this paper](https://cs.au.dk/~hosc/local/LaSC-4-3-pp223-242.pdf) about the `Self` programming language, which was largely the inspiration for JS's OO model (although there are some differences).

Comment: (Note: The first link above is intended as a good explanation of how this all works under the hood...I'm not particularly endorsing its recommendations. I think Javascript's conventional style of inheritance using constructor functions works fine, it's just a matter of understanding it.)

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify a bit and provide an example